# NoMethodError in NameController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, nomethoderror

I've run into an error in my application, to explain the context: a user has several cars, each car can make a tanking therefore my TankingLogsController is the following

```
class TankingLogsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])  
        @car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])
        @tankinglog = @cars.tanking_logs.build
    end
end
```

This is my routes.rb file

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :users
resources :users do
    resources :cars do
    resources :tanking_logs
end
end
...
```

I encountered this error:

```
NoMethodError in TankingLogsController#new

undefined method `tanking_logs' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/tanking_logs_controller.rb:5:in `new'
```

Why is my application failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very obvious error, and Ruby is telling you exactly what it is and where to find it.

You've written:

```
@car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])
@tankinglog = @cars.tanking_logs.build
```

You initialize a variable called `@car` on the first line, and you reference a second uninitialized variable `@cars` on the second line.

You have never initialized the `@cars` variable, so it is nil. Calling `@cars.tanking_logs` causes `undefined method 'tanking_logs' for nil:NilClass`, because you're effectively writing `nil.tanking_logs`.

The second line should be using `@car.tanking_logs`.